# hp sb40c and hp bl460c storage

Tags: raid, storage, hp

I have an HP ProLiant BL460c partnered with an HP SB40c blade server. The storage controller for the BL460c is HP Smart Array E200 while the SB40c's controller is P400. In my configuration, the ProLiant is running diskless. On the storage blade there's a 4 drive array on RAID 1+0 {Performance is very good in this citrix based virtual environment (12 vms)}.
The SB40c can hold up to 6 drives, and we need to add as many drives as possible. would that number be 2 more drives hence fully loading the storage blade and leaving the server blade diskless? or 4 drives: 2 on storage blade and 2 on server blade?
in other words, can we install drives on the server blade and make them be part of the array created via p400 controller on storage blade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that setup, you're limited to the six disks inside the existing storage blade. I'm assuming you're using BL460c G5 servers. If you were to move to the newer generations of that server (G6 or G7, for instance), you'd be able to use the [D2200sb Storage Blade](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13714_na/13714_na.html) (12-disk capacity). As-is, you can only add two more disks.

Answer (score 3):

Any drives you install in the server will be local drives, not accessible to the P400.